# How to get milliseconds from LocalDateTime in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, milliseconds, java-time

I am wondering if there is a way to get current milliseconds since 1-1-1970 (epoch) using the new `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` or `LocalDateTime` classes of Java 8.

The known way is below:

```
long currentMilliseconds = new Date().getTime();
```

or

```
long currentMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: What's wrong with `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: @DavidWallace He's trying to get the time of a Date, not the current time?

Comment: "... a way to get current milliseconds ..."

Comment: milliseconds counting from 1-1-1970. I was wandering if there is a method to get them using the new classes of Java 8 LocalDate, LocalTime and LocalDateTime, cause i didn't found one.

Comment: My understanding of the purpose for those classes is that it is a "human-focused" understanding of time, and `currentTimeMillis` would be irrelevant in that context.  Think Calendar + Wall-clock with really good precision, and no concerns about time zones and locality.  So there's no way to get back to "UTC Time" from a LocalTime

Comment: Similar Question: [*How to covert LocalDateTime to a Long?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73870816/642706) with [one good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73871279/642706).

Answer (score 450, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "current milliseconds" but I'll assume it's the number of milliseconds since the "epoch," namely midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

If you want to find the number of milliseconds since the epoch *right now,* then use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as [Anubian Noob has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944399/1441122). If so, there's no reason to use any of the new java.time APIs to do this.

However, maybe you already have a `LocalDateTime` or similar object from somewhere and you want to convert it to milliseconds since the epoch. It's not possible to do that directly, since the `LocalDateTime` family of objects has no notion of what time zone they're in. Thus time zone information needs to be supplied to find the time relative to the epoch, which is in UTC.

Suppose you have a `LocalDateTime` like this:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 5, 29, 18, 41, 16);
```

You need to apply the time zone information, giving a `ZonedDateTime`. I'm in the same time zone as Los Angeles, so I'd do something like this:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Of course, this makes assumptions about the time zone. And there are edge cases that can occur, for example, if the local time happens to name a time near the Daylight Saving Time (Summer Time) transition. Let's set these aside, but you should be aware that these cases exist.

Anyway, if you can get a valid `ZonedDateTime`, you can convert this to the number of milliseconds since the epoch, like so:

```
long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Note that [ZonedDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) already *has* the `getEpochSecond` method (via [ChronoZonedDateTime default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toEpochSecond--)). No need for the `Instant`.

Comment: Sure, if all you need is seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Ah well, I was imprecise: `ZonedDateTime` also has `Instant`s `getNano` method, so wouldn't you be able to just replace `inst` with `zdt` in your example?

Comment: Argh. `ChronoZonedDateTime` has `toEpochSecond` not `getEpochSecond`. So yes I think this allows skipping the use of `Instant`. I'll test and update.

Comment: Avoid the maths on nanos by using zdt.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND). Avoid all the maths by using zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()

Comment: @JodaStephen zdt.getLong instead of just get (which returns int)

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().offset)` there is also another solution without using `Zone`

Answer (score 147):

What I do so I don't specify a time zone is,

```
System.out.println("ldt " + LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
System.out.println("ctm " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

gives

```
ldt 1424812121078 
ctm 1424812121281
```

As you can see the numbers are the same except for a small execution time.

Just in case you don't like System.currentTimeMillis, use `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`

Comment: No, Epoch is relative to UTC but you get the current time from your local zone.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström the amount of milliseconds that have passed since the epoch is a fact independent of timezone. It's the same amount of milliseconds, no matter what time of day you call it. The two results are different because brian's machine took 203 milliseconds to execute the second command.

Comment: Is it ok to use UTC when the user maybe in a different timezone

Comment: @GilbertS you should probably never use this exact code, use the API as intended.  Date-time should always be UTC when stored on a computer or transmitted to another user.  It should usually be presented to the user as a local date time using their own time zone settings.

Comment: As @Fletch has already mentioned, the result has nothing to do with the timezone. The reason behind the difference is that it took 203 milliseconds to execute the second command. You can replace `System.out.println("ctm " + System.currentTimeMillis());` with `System.out.println("ldt " + LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());` i.e. execute the exact same statement twice and you will still see the difference equal to the no. of milliseconds elapsed since the last execution of the same statement.

Answer (score 26):

Since Java 8 you can call `java.time.Instant.toEpochMilli()`.

For example the call

```
final long currentTimeJava8 = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
```

gives you the same results as

```
final long currentTimeJava1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: "gives you the same results as" ... but takes more CPU power and stresses the garbage collector a lot more.

Comment: I'd like to see the above quantified (especially for normal usage - e.g. not for some performance critical real-time application...)

Answer (score 24):

To avoid ZoneId you can do:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0);

System.out.println("Initial Epoch (TimeInMillis): " + date.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(0)).toEpochMilli());
```

Getting 0 as value, that's right!

Comment: `ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(0)` it is the same as `ZoneOffset.UTC`

Comment: Yes, it was me upvoting @AntonNovopashin’s comment. Since you needed UTC, you’re fine (you might want to mention that in the answer). BTW `ZoneOffset` is a subclass of `ZoneId`, so I wouldn’t exactly say you have avoided it, but as long as you’re happy…

Comment: My first comment was a bit harsh, but wasn’t meant as offensive. You took offense. I am sorry. I have deleted it. Allow me to ask the other way around: what might be our reason for wanting to avoid `ZoneId`?

Comment: @OleV.V Is it ok to use UTC. Isn't only for people living in UTC timezone.

Comment: @GilbertS I don’t think anyone lives in UTC time zone. Using UTC for times that are used across time zones is recommended as a good practice. See for example [Java Best Practice for Date Manipulation/Storage for Geographically Diverse Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075780/java-best-practice-for-date-manipulation-storage-for-geographically-diverse-user). Or maybe I didn’t understand your question?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `java.sql.Timestamp` also to get milliseconds.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
long milliSeconds = Timestamp.valueOf(now).getTime();
System.out.println("MilliSeconds: "+milliSeconds);
```

Comment: You are ignoring the crucial need for a time zone. I do not recommend doing it this way. Also the `Timestamp` class is long outdated and filled with design problems, so I’d rather avoid it, especially when we can use the classes from `java.time` like `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Just curious about the design problems of `Timestamp`, Can you share some article on that? It helps me to avoid using `Timestamp` from my code as well. Thanks!

Comment: Just short, it’s implemented as a subclass of `Date` but often cannot be handled as a `Date`. Most of the methods inherited from `Date` and one constructor are deprecated. Its `toString` method uses the JVM’s time zone, which confuses many since the same `Timestamp` is printed differently on different computers ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset)).

Comment: This is perfect for unit testing. Just replace the now with `LocalDate.of(year, month, day)`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to workaround the "always UTC" values.

Answer (score 13):

To get the current time in milliseconds (since the epoch), use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score 13):

You can try this:

```
long diff = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation too.

Comment: if you use `LocalDateTime` without local offset (always use UTC only) then it's better to just use `Instant` for REST, Websockets and other logic, and then you can pass that `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` when you want to format date time for UI with local offset. In this case you don't use `LocalDateTime` at all

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now().toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().offset)` is easier

Answer (score 7):

Why didn't anyone mentioned the method `LocalDateTime.toEpochSecond()`:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = ... // whatever e.g. LocalDateTime.now()
long time2epoch = localDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This seems way shorter that many suggested answers above...

Comment: this is what I was looking for. That accepted answer was giving me the willies.

Comment: Accept its only available in API 26 :{

Comment: Because it gives only seconds. It's weird that there is no `toEpochMilli` method, taken into account the fact that you can specify even nanoseconds in LocalDateTime: there is a method `LocalDateTime.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond)`.

Comment: if you just knew the difference between seconds and milliseconds...

Comment: the question was about milliseconds  and the guy says that it is weird that nobody mentioned seconds :D

Answer (score 6):

In case of `LocalDate`, you can use the [`toEpochDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--) method. It returns the number of days since 01/01/1970. That number then can be easily converted to milliseconds:

```
long dateInMillis = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(myLocalDate.toEpochDay());
```

In case of `LocalDateTime`, you can use the [`toEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toEpochSecond-java.time.ZoneOffset-) method. It returns the number of seconds since 01/01/1970. That number then can be converted to milliseconds, too:

```
long dateTimeInMillis = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(myLocalDateTime.toEpochSecond());
```

Comment: The correct method is: `toEpochDay`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 5):

For LocalDateTime I do it this way:

```
LocalDateTime.of(2021,3,18,7,17,24,341000000)
    .toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset())
    .toEpochMilli()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Java 8 Clock, then you can use `clock.millis()` (although it recommends you use `clock.instant()` to get a Java 8 Instant, as it's more accurate).

Why would you use a Java 8 clock? So in your DI framework you can create a Clock bean:

```
@Bean
public Clock getClock() {
    return Clock.systemUTC();
}
```

and then in your tests you can easily Mock it:

```
@MockBean private Clock clock;
```

or you can have a different bean:

```
@Bean
public Clock getClock() {
    return Clock.fixed(instant, zone);
}
```

which helps with tests that assert dates and times immeasurably.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more simpler:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
Assert.assertEquals(System.currentTimeMillis(), zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

get the millis like System.currentTimeMillis() (from UTC).

Answer (score 3):

Date and time as String to Long (millis):

```
String dateTimeString = "2020-12-12T14:34:18.000Z";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime
        .parse(dateTimeString, formatter);

Long dateTimeMillis = localDateTime
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toInstant()
        .toEpochMilli();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  default LocalDateTime getDateFromLong(long timestamp) {
    try {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    } catch (DateTimeException tdException) {
      //  throw new 
    }
}

default Long getLongFromDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest conversion:

```
Instant.from(localDateTime).toEpochMilli()
```

SORRY this does not work and gies the following error:

```
"Unsupported field: InstantSeconds",
"  java.base/java.time.LocalDate.get0(LocalDate.java:708)",
"  java.base/java.time.LocalDate.getLong(LocalDate.java:687)",
"  java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.getLong(LocalDateTime.java:720)",
"  java.base/java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:373)",
"  com.capitalone.rupol.ruleengine.util.LocalDateSerializer.serialize(LocalDateSerializer.java:25)",
"Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: 2024-02-03T00:00 of type java.time.LocalDateTime",
"  java.base/java.time.Instant.from(Instant.java:378)",
"  com.capitalone.rupol.ruleengine.util.LocalDateSerializer.serialize(LocalDateSerializer.java:25)",
"  com.capitalone.rupol.ruleengine.util.LocalDateSerializer.serialize(LocalDateSerializer.java:11)",
"  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeOptionalFields(MapSerializer.java:869)",
"  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:760)",
```

The LocalDateTime does not carry a time zone.  The Instant does not carry a time zone.  Strangely, many of the other conversions require specifying a time zone that you don't need.   This avoids using a time zone offset at any step, and converts internally from millis to millis.

It is strange that the LocalDateTime does not offer a conversion to Instant, since both LocalDateTime and Instant do not involve any representation of a time zone, but this factory method does the job.