# How can I create a Java 8 LocalDate from a long Epoch time in Milliseconds?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I have an external API that returns me dates as `long`s, represented as milliseconds since the beginning of the Epoch.

With the old style Java API, I would simply construct a `Date` from it with

```
Date myDate = new Date(startDateLong)
```

What is the equivalent in Java 8's `LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime` classes?

I am interested in converting the point in time represented by the `long` to a `LocalDate` in my current local timezone.

Comment: Well you have to start by working out what time zone you care about. A "milliseconds since epoch" value gives you an instant in time... that could refer to different dates in different time zones. Bear in mind that `java.util.Date` was never really a date in the way that `LocalDate` is - it was an instant in time as well.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate, which covers the conversion of `java.util.Date` into `LocalDate`

Comment: Note: This Q&A is also valuable for those trying to convert `File.lastModified()` (epoch millis) to `LocalDate(Time)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get milliseconds from LocalDateTime in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944370/how-to-get-milliseconds-from-localdatetime-in-java-8)

Comment: @GeorgeSiggouroglou That questions asks the opposite of this question, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are correct, I hurried, I removed the vote to close.

Answer (score 600, accepted):

If you have the milliseconds since the Epoch and want to convert them to a local date using the current local timezone, you can use [`Instant.ofEpochMilli(long epochMilli)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-)

```
LocalDate date =
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

but keep in mind that even the system’s default time zone may change, thus the same `long` value may produce different result in subsequent runs, even on the same machine.

Further, keep in mind that `LocalDate`, unlike `java.util.Date`, really represents a date, not a date and time.

Otherwise, you may use a `LocalDateTime`:

```
LocalDateTime date =
    LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: +1 from me for more detailed explanation. By the way, even a non-system zone can change (by tzupdater-tool or by jdk-change) and hence produce different results before and after.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild: I wasn’t focusing on hardcoded timezones but rather comparing with timezones specified by the user, read from a configuration file or environment variables, where the programmer naturally assumes that the may change. Hardcoded timezones are indeed much like the system default; the programmer is tempted into thinking they were never changing…

Comment: Can I use `LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond()` with, for example `milliseconds / 1000` ?

Comment: @Demigod you can, when you think specifying a `ZoneOffset` is better than specifying a `ZoneId` (you can not use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` anymore, or at least not without converting it for a particular `Instant`, but when you have an `Instant`, why not use `LocalDateTime.ofInstant`…).

Comment: @holger, I have a long (millis). Why ZoneId.systemDefault() cannot be used?

Comment: @Demigod `LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(…)` requires an actual `ZoneOffset`, but  `ZoneId.systemDefault()` returns a `ZoneId`. A `ZoneId` can map to different offsets, depending on the point of time you’re referring to. That’s what `LocalDateTime.ofInstant` does for you, converting the specified `ZoneId` according to the provided `Instant`.

Comment: I came hoping to find a more readable solution than this, what a downgrade from the old java.util approach....

Comment: @MihaiMorcov it’s exactly the problem of the “old java.util approach” that it didn’t handle the semantic difference between a *local* data-time and a long value representing an *instant*.

Comment: Epoch is defined as UTC and should be therefore be timezone independent, so the ZoneId should always be UTC.

Comment: @PlexQ The specified timezone is not relevant for the Epoch, which indeed is timezone independent, but for the semantics of the resulting `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`. You can specify any timezone you want, as long as it is consistent with the subsequent use of these result objects. Think of what happens when you deal with multiple objects created by different methods. The typical use cases for *local* date or datetimes incorporate the system default timezone, e.g. `LocalDateTime.now()` ≈ `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()), ZoneId.systemDefault())`…

Comment: Some ZoneID miss nanosecond and millisecond.

Comment: @fjjiaboming there are no nanoseconds in the epochmillis in the first place. For any other loss of precision, name an actual example.

Comment: @MihaiMorcov Agreed. What a nightmare. I am converting some really old code and I wanted a simple way to use the long value of a file last mod date and I have to do all this? A real shame.

Comment: @Pryftan “to use the long value of a file last mod date” is a very unspecific task. Are you sure you actually need a `LocalDate`? Maybe whatever you actually want to do with the long value, can be done with the `Instant` created via `Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue)` too.

Answer (score 64):

You can start with [Instant.ofEpochMilli(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-):

```
LocalDate date =
  Instant.ofEpochMilli(startDateLong)
  .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
  .toLocalDate();
```

Comment: +1 for being explicit about time zone. If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied in determining the date. For any given moment the date varies around the world by time zone as a new day dawns earlier in the east.

Answer (score 18):

I think I have a better answer.

```
new Timestamp(longEpochTime).toLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: new Timestamp(ts).toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate()

Comment: I mean - if you don't mind importing javal.sql.Timestamp, which, given Java's monolithic nature I suppose is fine because it's just all part of the JVM... but feels a bit smelly, but I still like it better as it recognized epoch is fundamentally in UTC.

Comment: The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Your code will use the JVM’s time zone setting, but since this setting can be changed by another part of your program or another program running in the same JVM, we cannot be quite sure what it is.

Comment: It's always better to be explicit about which timezone is used. Using the old java.sql.Timestamp has the drawback of having the system timezone applied implicitly which usually causes confusion among developers.

Comment: @PlexQ Java is not monolithic anymore. To use `java.sql.Timestamp` when using modules, you have to declare a dependency to the [module `java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/module-summary.html), which will in turn introduce dependencies to `java.xml` and `java.logging`.

Comment: @Holger True, though I haven't seen anyone building on anything above Java 11 in the wild yet.

Comment: @PlexQ well, the modularization has been introduced in Java 9.

Answer (score 8):

A simple version based on [@Michael Piefel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318605/5006866):

```java
LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(Duration.ofMillis(epochMillis).toDays());
```

Comment: This works perfectly well as it takes leap years into account.

Answer (score 7):

Timezones and stuff aside, a very simple alternative to `new Date(startDateLong)` could be `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(startDateLong / 86400000L)`

Comment: I think you should at least explain what the 86400000L stands for.

Comment: I thought it was very easy to spot that it’s the number of milliseconds in a day.

Comment: For some it is, and I figured that only that would make sense, but without recalculation how many ms a day really has, I wouldn't be sure. Just speaking for myself, I don't know this number so well that I automatically know what it stands for.

Comment: Note also that the accepted answer really is the best answer, it just looks overwhelming. My simple hack just my be enough in many case. It’s a pity that `java.time` does not include `DateTimeConstants` as Joda did.

Comment: `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(startDateLong)`

Answer (score 3):

replace now.getTime() with your long value.

```
//GET UTC time for current date
        Date now= new Date();
        //LocalDateTime utcDateTimeForCurrentDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(now.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
        LocalDate localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(now.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDate();
        DateTimeFormatter dTF2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        System.out.println(" formats as " + dTF2.format(utcDateTimeForCurrentDateTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this alternative solution for LocalDateTime:

```
public static LocalDateTime increaseByMillis(final LocalDateTime ldt, final long millis)
    {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()+millis), ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId()));
    }
```

Test:

```
LocalDateTime test = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime increased = MyUtilsAbc.increaseByMillis(test, 1000);

        Assert.assertEquals("Increase of LocalDateTime not working (anymore)!", test.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) +1, increased.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Answer (score -7):

In a specific case where your epoch seconds timestamp comes from SQL or is related to SQL somehow, you can obtain it like this:

```
long startDateLong = <...>

LocalDate theDate = new java.sql.Date(startDateLong).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: This does not really relate much to the asked question

Comment: @KetanR, I disagree. The question is "how to obtain a `LocalDate` from `epoch-millis`", and I show how, using `java.sql.Date` for shorthand. This approach makes sense in code that's already dealing with JDBC in some capacity, and it works just fine. If you still not convinced, explain how is it not related to initial question.

Comment: If you read the question, it says "external API that returns me dates as longs" and you are explaining how this conversion can be done if you are receiving long date from SQL. Your answer does explain a very specific case of the date conversion but its not really relevant to question that has been ask ed.Your explanation could be a valid answer to some other related quesiton though.

Comment: @KetanR, if one receives long date from SQL, I'd advise to change his schema so he no longer receives dates in such form. However, if one receives dates as millis-timestamps from elsewhere (the external API), and immediately uses these dates to make JDBC queries, then `java.sql.Date` approach is among the shortest available, code-wise, and I'd say it's not all that useful to go though `Instant` with all the intermediate temporal objects when the end result is the same.

Comment: As i have already said and is evident from your latest explanation, your answer is correct but not for the question at hand  Question says: "I am interested in converting the point in time represented by the long to a LocalDate in my current local timezone.
" your answer tells: "receive dates as millis-timestamps, and immediately use these dates to make JDBC queries". I dont understand what is not clear here ?