# java 8 instant with time 00:00:00 gives time 02:00:00 after conversion to util,Date

Tags: java, date, time, java.time.instant

I have a problem in converting java.time.Instant to java.util.Date:

```
System.out.println(item.getStart()); // getStart returns instant
System.out.println(Date.from(item.getStart()));
```

gives output:

```
2017-08-29T00:00:00Z
Tue Aug 29 02:00:00 CEST 2017
```

Why in date time is 02:00:00? And how to do convertion with time 00:00:00

Comment: Both correspond to the same instant. But `Instant` is printed in UTC and `Date` is printed in the JVM default timezone. You don't convert the `Date` object because [it has no format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). If you want to convert to a `String`, though, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/7605325

Comment: What you have observed, is the expected and correct behaviour. Your `Date` holds the same point in time. `System.out.println()` implicitly calls `Date.toString()`, which in turn converts the time to a string in Central European time zone, producing the output you see.

Comment: “And how to do convertion with time 00:00:00?” You already got a `Date` with time 00:00:00 UTC. Don’t let yourself fool by the output from `toString()`.

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the `Date::toString` lies. The method applies the JVM’s current default time zone, implying the zone is assigned to the `Date` object when actually a `Date` is always in UTC. One of many reasons to avoid this terrible old class. Use only the java.time classes instead.

Comment: As Hugo commented, **midnight UTC *is* the same moment as 2 AM in central Europe**. If someone in Reykjavík Iceland watching their clock strike midnight says to their friend on the telephone sitting in Paris France, "Wow, look at the time", the Parisian responds "Mais oui, 2 AM".

Answer (score 3):

In `2017-08-29T00:00:00Z` the `Z` means `Zulu`, which means `UTC+0`. 
So it describtes exactly the same moment in time as `Tue Aug 29 02:00:00 CEST 2017` which is `UTC+2`

It gets printed as CEST because the default implementation of the `toString()` method is using the default time zone.

You could try using Java8 `LocalDate` instead. It hasn’t got any time-of-day information.

How to do the conversion you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187046/1199731

Comment: Does this helps you tomasz?