# getting Out of Range Compile Time Error in the Date Constructor

Tags: java

I am getting a date value as 1598331600000 from a API call

I am trying to convert this to Readable format using SimpleDateFormat

But i am getting Out of Range Compile Time Error in the Date Constructor

This is my Program

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Date date = new java.sql.Date(1598331600000);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");

        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

        System.out.println(formattedDate);

    }

}
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this error .

Comment: [How can I create a Java 8 LocalDate from a long Epoch time in Milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183146/how-can-i-create-a-java-8-localdate-from-a-long-epoch-time-in-milliseconds)

Comment: What are you using `java.sql.Date` for? That class is a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date`, and both are long outdated. Also `java.sql.Date` was originally meant for transferring dates to and from SQL databases, it’s rather pointless to use it for anything else. For a date use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use [java-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) date time api, and stop using legacy [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(1598331600000l)
       .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
       .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyyyy")) //08252020
```

Comment: Two further recommendations: (1) use underscore as thousand separator (2) use upper case `L` since lower case `l` easily reads as digit  `1` (in many fonts). So `1_598_331_600_000L`

Answer (score 3):

`1598331600000` without a suffix is treated as an `int`, and this value is too big for it (`int` can hold values up to around 2 billion, `2^31 - 1`). Use `L` suffix for `long` type, which can hold values up to `2^63 - 1`: `1598331600000L`.

Answer (score 0):

Your value here is treated as integer.

```
Date date = new java.sql.Date(1598331600000);
```

The constructor can take Long values. Like this :

```
long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();
Date date = new java.sql.Date(millis);
```

Hence it is throwing the error.

Try out this code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        /*long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();  <---- This also works
        Date date = new java.sql.Date(millis);*/
        Date date = new java.sql.Date(1598331600000L);  // <---Look the L for Long here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
08252020
```