# Convert 13 digit UTC epoch time to Java Instant UTC format?

Tags: java, date, datetime, utc

I need a java function to convert 13 digit epoch utc time in milliseconds to Java Instant time in UTC. Can anyone please help?

input : 1611476543540
output : 2021-01-24 08:23:13

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183146/how-can-i-create-a-java-8-localdate-from-a-long-epoch-time-in-milliseconds may be a better dupe, if the aim is to get an `Instant`, rather than a `Date`.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1611476543540L), ZoneId.of("UTC"))` (given as there are many differing variants). The ISO standard gives a T instead of blank, but there are predefined formats.

Comment: @JoopEggen - You need just `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1611476543540L)`.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive also for formating with a different format?Probably. Aaah, everytime I do too much.

Comment: @JoopEggen - For formatting, *Yes, one needs to do it in your way but OP's requirement is just to get `Instant`*.

Comment: Instant.ofEpochMilli(1611476543540L) worked for me. thanks Joop