# Getting the startime and endtime of the day in epochmillis for different timezones - java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am trying to get the start time (00:00:00) and the end time (23:59:59) of a day in the PST time zone. I have tried the following code, but for some reason, I am only getting the start and end times in UTC. I have tried changing the timezone to include "America/Los_angeles", but the output timestamp is always showing start and end times for GMT/UTC.

My code:

```
val time_zone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")
val today_date = LocalDate.now(time_zone).plusDays(0)
val start_time = today_date + " " + "00:00:00"
val end_time = today_date + " " + "23:59:59"

val date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
val start_millis = date_format.parse(start_time).getTime();
val end_millis = date_format.parse(end_time).getTime();

start_millis
```

Output:

```
res375: Long = 1656460799000
```

In the epoch converter, `1656460799000` gives me this:
[image: The start time is 00:00 in UTC, not in America/Los_Angeles time]

Anything I am missing here? Should I update any package, etc.?

Comment: I believe the question has been already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187046/17949945

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Java 8 LocalDate from a long Epoch time in Milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183146/how-can-i-create-a-java-8-localdate-from-a-long-epoch-time-in-milliseconds)

Comment: tried that, didnt work well. I tried SystemDefault, it still didnt work. Also, the solutions for Instant.() seem to work only for the current time, not which ever time I want.

Comment: *Instant.() seem to work only for the current time* - that's incorrect check this code https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sI3 it'll bring you back to 1970. It **does** work with any amount of milliseconds you provide.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Those are not quite duplicates. Those questions are about a moment. This question is about a pair of moments, tracking the beginning and end of a full day. This Question here is *very* likely a duplicate, but I did not find original. Hence my Answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque OK, retracting the close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes only.

No need to ever use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`, and the other terrible legacy date-time classes. If need be, you can convert to and fro via new conversion methods added to the old classes.

## Start of day

> I am trying to get the start time (00:00:00)

Do not assume the day starts at 00:00. Some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day using `LocalDate#atStartOfDay`.

## End of day

> the end time (23:59:59) of a day

You would be missing an entire last second of the day with that approach.

Date-time work is commonly done with the Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a day starts with the first moment of the day, and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the following day. Half-Open approach neatly contains that full last second of the day.

## Time zones

> PST time zone.

There is no such thing as a time zone named `PST`. Such 2-4 letter pseudo-zones are used by the popular media to indicate a hint about the time zone. But these pseudo-zones are *not* standardized, and are not even unique! Use only for localized presentation to humans, never for data storage or data exchange.

[Real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are named with `Continent/Region`.

Perhaps by “PST” you meant “Pacific Standard Time”, which often indicates `America/Tijuana`, or `America/Los_Angeles` or `America/Vancouver` or others.

Or perhaps by “PST” you meant “Philippines Standard Time” covering the `Asia/Manila` time zone.

## Example code

Capture the current moment as seen in a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Extract the date.

```
LocalDate today = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

And determine the first moment of the following day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfFollowingDay = today.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

You may want to see the length of time. Not all days are 24 hours.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStartOfDay , zdtStartOfFollowingDay ) ;
```

Adjust both moments to UTC by extracting an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object. That class represents a moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant start = zdtStartOfDay.toInstant() ;
Instant end = zdtStartOfFollowingDay.toInstant() ;
```

For each, get the count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
long startMilli = start.toEpochMilli() ;
long endMilli = end.toEpochMilli() ;
```

However, I strongly recommend against tracking time as a count of milliseconds. This approach is confusing, as at least a [couple dozen epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) points are commonly used. And a `long` cannot be interpreted by a human reader, so mistakes may go unnoticed.

Instead, data storage and data exchange should generally be done as text using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
String startText = start.toString() ;
String endText = end.toString() ;
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

You may want to add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This gives you access to the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class, to represent a span of time as a pair of `Instant` objects.

```
Interval allDayLongToday = org.threeten.extra.Interval.of( start , end ) ;
```

This class provides several helpful methods. These include `contains`, `encloses`, `abuts`, `union`, `intersection`, and more.

```
Instant invoiceRecorded = … some `Instant` ;
boolean invoiceRecordedToday = allDayLongToday.contains( invoiceRecorded ) ;
```

Comment: very detailed and helpful answer. thanks a lot!

Comment: Very instructive answer. Didn't know about  ThreeTen's `Interval`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko ThreeTen-Extra also provides the equivalent for a pair of `LocalDate` objects, [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html).

Comment: Sorry for off-topic. It seems like [this question about parsing Duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830251/datetimeparseexception-text-cannot-be-parsed-to-a-duration/72830462#72830462) has been associated with a wrong one (it has been closed as a duplicate). Current "original" question is related to `TimeUtil` and it's deprecated method [`parseDuration()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/TimeUtil.html#parseDuration-java.lang.String-). I've requested reopening. Am I correct in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this section to your code:

```
date_format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
```

Then it will work as you want :)