# DateTimeParseException: Text cannot be parsed to a Duration

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, duration

I am having an issue with parsing the `Duration`:

```
// import java.time.Duration;
...
Duration d = Duration.parse("1h");
...
```

If my understanding of the documentation is correct, I should be able to use `1h` value, but I'm getting me the following exception:

```
DateTimeParseException: Text cannot be parsed to a Duration
```

I retrieve the `1h` value from some configuration, for the sake of simplicity I've omitted the other code.

How can I fix this?

Comment: According to [which docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: "_According to the docs_" - Not sure what docs you are referring to. You can see a discussion of the format, with examples, in the [documentation for `Duration.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: `TimeUtil` **isn't** a part of the JDK and [`TimeUtil.parseDuration()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/TimeUtil.html#parseDuration-java.lang.String-) is **DEPRECATED**, hence the currently associated question isn't suitable as the original for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> The string starts with an optional sign, denoted by the ASCII negative or positive symbol. If negative, the whole period is negated. **The ASCII letter** `"P"` is next in **upper or lower case**. There are then four sections, each consisting of a number and a suffix. The sections have suffixes in ASCII of "D", "H", "M" and "S" for days, hours, minutes and seconds, accepted in upper or lower case. The suffixes must occur in order. The **ASCII letter** `"T"` must occur **before the first occurrence**, if any, of an **hour**, **minute** or **second section**. At least one of the four sections must be present ...

It is mandatory for the string you are parsing to start with `"PT"` either in upper case or in lower case.

Letter `"H"` in hour section also can be either in upper case or in lower case.

```
System.out.println(Duration.parse("pt1h"));
```

*Output:*

```
PT1H
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not using correct format, use below -

```
Duration d = Duration.parse("PT1H");
```