# Spring returns lot of information about date

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am newbie to spring working on a spring web app. In the app there's one API which should return the date which I saved earlier using another api. The date is consumed on iOS. It's all working fine but the amount of data returned as part of the date is huge and I am wondering if it's possible to turn it off. Here's the sample of the data:

```
"availability": {
"offset": {
"totalSeconds": -25200
"id": "-07:00"
"rules": {
"fixedOffset": true
"transitions": [0]
"transitionRules": [0]
}-
}-
"zone": {
"id": "America/Los_Angeles"
"rules": {
"fixedOffset": false
"transitions": [127]
0:  {
"offsetBefore": {
"totalSeconds": -28378
"id": "-07:52:58"
"rules": {
"fixedOffset": true
"transitions": [0]
"transitionRules": [0]
}-
}-
"offsetAfter": {
"totalSeconds": -28800
"id": "-08:00"
"rules": {
"fixedOffset": true
"transitions": [0]
"transitionRules": [0]
}-
}-
"duration": {
"seconds": -422
"negative": true
"zero": false
"units": [2]
0:  "SECONDS"
1:  "NANOS"
-
"nano": 0
}-
"gap": false
"overlap": true
"dateTimeAfter": {
"year": 1883
"month": "NOVEMBER"
"dayOfMonth": 18
"dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY"
"dayOfYear": 322
"monthValue": 11
"hour": 12
"minute": 0
"second": 0
"nano": 0
"chronology": {
"id": "ISO"
"calendarType": "iso8601"
}-
}-
"dateTimeBefore": {
"year": 1883
"month": "NOVEMBER"
"dayOfMonth": 18
"dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY"
"dayOfYear": 322
"monthValue": 11
"hour": 12
"minute": 7
"second": 2
"nano": 0
"chronology": {
"id": "ISO"
"calendarType": "iso8601"
}-
}-
"instant": {
"nano": 0
"epochSecond": -2717640000
}-
}-
1:  {
"offsetBefore": {
"totalSeconds": -28800
"id": "-08:00"
"rules": {
"fixedOffset": true
"transitions": [0]
"transitionRules": [0]
}-
}-
```

I don't want all this data, because my query is taking long time to return. Am I doing something wrong or missing some flag which tells what to return. The date is stored as ZonedDateTime originally, or shall I store the date in some other format?

Comment: What library are you using to serialize into JSON? You may need a custom serializer which only renders specified fields.

Comment: I am using spring boot so I think it auto configures jackson json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show the POJO you are serializing. So I bet you are using some Date abstraction like Joda Time's or Java8's `LocalDateTime`. You may want to change this POJO to contain only simple `Long` timestamp or just `Date`, which should be serialized into amount of milliseconds from epoch 1970.

For mentioned conversion take a look at these SO answers:

[Converting between java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431234/converting-between-java-time-localdatetime-and-java-util-date)

[How to get milliseconds from LocalDateTime in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944370/how-to-get-milliseconds-from-localdatetime-in-java-8)

Comment: Thanks, I am also thinking of storing the date in epoch relative to UTC instead of actual date in some format. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @puru020 Using count-from-epoch is unintuitive, masks the meaning of the values, and is therefore prone to error. I strongly recommend considering the use of standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for serializing date-time values into a string representation. These formats are sensible and intuitive. The ISO 8601 standard is used by default in both the java.time and Joda-Time frameworks for parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. Also, big tip: Use UTC. For example: `2016-03-13T04:50:31Z` where the `Z` is `Zulu` meaning UTC.

Comment: Thanks Basil. I was actually using this format earlier "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" with ZonedDateTime in my rest api. The data was being saved correctly in mongodb like "ISODate("2016-03-14T01:45:28.731Z")". But when querying for value I was getting the response above which is huge data and was trying to avoid it. Do you know if there's way to tell spring to return just the date?