# How to convert Java LocalDate to milliseconds

Tags: java, utc, epoch, milliseconds, localdate

I am trying to convert a date formatted in `yyyy-mm-dd` to `LocalDate` to milliseconds with this code.

```
LocalDate.parse("2022-08-01", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

It returns `1659283200000` which is not correct and behind 1 day. Is there better solution for this? The expected value is `1659312000000` in UTC.

Comment: Doesn't LocalDate take the local timezone into account?

Comment: seems to have been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945792/8919169

Comment: @MMZK1526 I am not sure either :)

Comment: @MMZK1526 `LocalDate` doesn't. Local just means it doesn't have a timezone part. However, `.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())` does take local timezone into account :)

Comment: @BriceHarismendy I need to parse date, not just the current date and I do not have time.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS What do you get if you print out the result after `.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())`? Also, what is your timezone?

Comment: @marstran How would I print `ZonedDateTime`? GMT+8 is the timezone

Comment: In that case the result you get is exactly correct. It equals Sunday 31. July 2022 16:00:00 UTC, which in turn equals 1 August 00:00 at UTC offset +08:00.

Comment: you want it "in UTC", but is `ZoneId.systemDefault()` returning UTC ? maybe it should be `ZoneOffset.UTC` ? (I can't test without some additional effort since my system is set to UTC - I get the *correct* value for both)

Comment: I've confirmed that `.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)` gives the result you are expecting.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes but there is a bit adjustment of 16:00:00 which is probably due to `ZoneId.systemDefault()` which uses the local zone?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, if you want a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

By the way, no need to specify a formatting pattern. Your input text complies with the ISO 8601 standard used by default in the *java.time* classes for parsing/generating text.

```
long millis =
    LocalDate
    .parse(
        "2022-08-01"
    )
    .atStartOfDay(
        ZoneId.systemDefault()
    )
    .toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()
;
```

## Time Zone

I imagine the problem with getting an unexpected result is the time zone. Your results will vary by time zone.

Understand that **the day starts earlier in the east**. At any moment, it can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan  while still “yesterday” in Edmonton Alberta Canada  .

[image]

(photo: [NASA](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:First_Picture_of_the_Earth_and_Moon_in_a_Single_Frame_-_GPN-2002-000202.jpg))

To avoid surprises, specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly rather than relying on the JVM’s current default time zone.

### Example

Same date used in examples below, for two time zones and one offset.

```
String input = "2022-08-01" ;
```

#### Tokyo

```
ZoneId zoneIdTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;

long millisTokyo =
    LocalDate
    .parse(
       input
    )
    .atStartOfDay(
        zoneIdTokyo
    )
    .toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()
;
```

#### Edmonton

```
ZoneId zoneIdEdmonton = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;

long millisEdmonton =
    LocalDate
    .parse(
       input
    )
    .atStartOfDay(
        zoneIdEdmonton
    )
    .toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()
;
```

#### UTC (offset of zero)

```
ZoneOffset offsetUtc = ZoneOffset.UTC ;

long millisUtc =
    LocalDate
    .parse(
       input
    )
    .atStartOfDay(
        offsetUtc
    )
    .toInstant()
    .toEpochMilli()
;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Tokyo: " + millisTokyo ) ;
System.out.println( "Edmonton: " + millisEdmonton ) ;
System.out.println( "UTC: " + millisUtc ) ;
```

See this code run live at Ideone.com.

> Tokyo: 1659279600000
>
> Edmonton: 1659333600000
>
> UTC: 1659312000000

## Interval

You said:

> The input date String should represent the current date and past 30 days which should be based on user's timezone. Example is 2022-07-08 to 2022-08-08

I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. Doing so gives you access to the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class to represent a span of time as a pair of `Instant` objects.

```
Interval intervalOfPrior30DaysInUtc ( LocalDate end ) {
    return 
        Interval
        .of(
            end.minusDays( 30 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant() ,
            end.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant() 
        )
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was solved by changing `ZoneId.systemDefault()` with `ZoneOffset.UTC`. The input date String should represent the current date and past 30 days which should be based on user's timezone. Example is `2022-07-08` to `2022-08-08`

Comment: @OleV.V. Done ☑️